# Coda-like popup bubble on page load and hover? - jQuery

Tags: jquery, popup, hover

I'm using the Coda-like bubble on my site from this: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/

I was wondering if it's possible to make the bubble show up directly after the page loaded, let it stay for a few seconds and then hide it again, while still being able to make it appear afterwards when you hover over the trigger?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
    $('.bar').each(function() {
        // options
        var distance = 5;
        var time = 250;
        var hideDelay = 1000;

        var hideDelayTimer = null;

        // tracker
        var beingShown = false;
        var shown = false;

        var trigger = $('.trigger', this);
        var popup = $('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);

        // set the mouseover and mouseout on both element
        $([trigger.get(0), popup.get(0)]).mouseover(function() {
            // stops the hide event if we move from the trigger to the popup element
            if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);

            // don't trigger the animation again if we're being shown, or already visible
            if (beingShown || shown) {
                return;
            } else {
                beingShown = true;

                // reset position of popup box
                popup.css({
                    top: 410,
                    left: 164,
                    display: 'block' // brings the popup back in to view
                })

                // (we're using chaining on the popup) now animate it's opacity and position
                .animate({
                    top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                    opacity: 1
                }, time, 'swing', function() {
                    // once the animation is complete, set the tracker variables
                    beingShown = false;
                    shown = true;
                });
            }
        }).mouseout(function() {
            // reset the timer if we get fired again - avoids double animations
            if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);

            // store the timer so that it can be cleared in the mouseover if required
            hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                hideDelayTimer = null;
                popup.animate({
                    top: '-=' + distance + 'px',
                    opacity: 0
                }, time, 'swing', function() {
                    // once the animate is complete, set the tracker variables
                    shown = false;
                    // hide the popup entirely after the effect (opacity alone doesn't do the job)
                    popup.css('display', 'none');
                });
            }, hideDelay);
        });
    });
});

});
```

I'm very thankful for your help, and I apologise if this is very easy and obvious! I'm horribly new at jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will help you to stay and hide the popup.

```
        label.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e)
          {                 
                   if(hideDelayTimer)
                   clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                   label.appendChild(popup);

          });

         label.addEventListener("mouseout",function()
           {
                  hideDelayTimer=setTimeout(function()
                 {
                      label.removeChild(popup);

                 },hideDelay);

           });
```